# Elapsed Time when using .ReplaceRange in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a class called Templates

```
public class Templates
{
   public string Name;
   public List<TemplateLines> TemplateLines
}

public class TemplateLines 
{
   public string ProductName;
   public string ProductCode;
}
```

my problem is that when I try to use ".ReplaceRange? it takes 10 seconds to complete

```
public ObservableRangeCollection<Templates> ProductTemplatesList { get; init; } = new();

templates = await templateService.GetProductTemplatesWithTemplateLines
ProductTemplatesList.ReplaceRange(templates);
```

Is there another faster way for this?

this is the code for Xaml that I think is i think making the code slower. What I want on my UI is to have a expander header with the Template Name and expander content with the TemplateLines.
Currently I am using nested stacklayouts using BindableLayout.ItemsSource

```
        <ScrollView Margin="0,-15,0,0">
            <StackLayout>
                <StackLayout IsVisible="{x:Binding IsLoading, Converter={x:StaticResource ReverseBooleanConverter}}" 
                         BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{x:Binding ProductTemplatesList}"
                         Spacing="0">
                    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ProductTemplateModel">
                            <extensions:Expander
                            IsExpanded="{x:Binding IsExpanded}">
                                <extensions:Expander.Header>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{x:StaticResource JtiPurpleLight}">
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20,10">
                                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Binding IsSelected}"/>
                                            <Label
                                            Text="{x:Binding Name}"
                                            FontAttributes="Bold" 
                                            TextColor="Black" 
                                            Style="{x:StaticResource MediumTextBold}"/>
                                            <Label
                                            Grid.Column="1"
                                            Margin="10,0"
                                            FontFamily="JTI"
                                            FontSize="25"
                                            Text="{x:Static common:ArrowDown}"
                                            TextColor="Black"
                                            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                                                <Label.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger
                                                    Binding="{x:Binding IsExpanded}"
                                                    TargetType="Label"
                                                    Value="true">
                                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Static common:ArrowUp}" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Label.Triggers>
                                            </Label>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray" Margin="0,-5,0,0"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </extensions:Expander.Header>
                                <extensions:Expander.Content>
                                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{x:Binding ProductTemplateLines}">
                                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ProductTemplateLineModel">
                                                <controls:TappableStack TappedCommand="{x:Binding Source={x:Reference TemplatesTab},
                                                            Path=BindingContext.ProductDetailsCommand}"
                                                            TappedCommandParameter="{x:Binding ProductId}">
                                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="20,10">
                                                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{x:Binding IsSelected}"/>
                                                        <StackLayout Spacing="5">
                                                            <Label 
                                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                            Text="{x:Binding Name}"
                                                            TextColor="Black"
                                                            Style="{x:StaticResource SmallText}"
                                                            FontFamily="RM"/>
                                                            <Label Margin="0,-5,0,0">
                                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                                        <Span Text="{x:Static i18n:Translator.Product_ProductCode}" TextColor="Black" Style="{x:StaticResource SmallText}"/>
                                                                        <Span Text=" :  " TextColor="Black" Style="{x:StaticResource SmallText}"/>
                                                                        <Span Text="{x:Binding ProductCode}" TextColor="Black" Style="{x:StaticResource SmallText}"/>
                                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                                            </Label>
                                                        </StackLayout>
                                                        <Label
                                                        FontFamily="CompanyX"
                                                        FontSize="Large"
                                                        Text="{x:Static common:ArrowRight}"
                                                        TextColor="Black"
                                                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                        HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"/>
                                                    </StackLayout>
                                                    <BoxView HeightRequest="1" Color="LightGray"/>
                                                </controls:TappableStack>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </extensions:Expander.Content>
                            </extensions:Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                </StackLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Comment: It ProductTemplatesList bound to anything?  If so, it's possible whatever object ProductTemplatesList bound to has a problem.

Comment: how big is the original collection?  how big is the new one?

Comment: @Jason original collection is empty , and new one is 3 Templates with 20 TemplateLines in each.

Comment: Then its the UI taking the time. ReplaceRange itself is nearly instantaneous. **Add to question** the xaml or code that displays the UI from that list.

Comment: added the xaml code

Comment: You can try to do a single sample to test if the UI takes time or not. There are so many layout nesting in your project.